# How to efficiently select dataframe columns containing a certain value in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose you have a dataframe in spark (string type) and you want to drop any column that contains "foo". In the example dataframe below, you would drop column "c2" and "c3" but keep "c1". However I'd like the solution to generalize to large numbers of columns and rows.

```
    +-------------------+
    |   c1|   c2|     c3|
    +-------------------+
    | this|  foo|  hello|
    | that|  bar|  world|
    |other|  baz| foobar|
    +-------------------+
```

My solution is to scan every column in the dataframe then aggregate the results using the dataframe API and built in functions.
So, scanning each column could be done like this (I'm new to scala please excuse syntax mistakes):

`df = df.select(df.columns.map(c => col(c).like("foo"))`

Logically, I would have an intermediate dataframe like this:

```
    +--------------------+
    |    c1|    c2|    c3|
    +--------------------+
    | false|  true| false|
    | false| false| false|
    | false| false|  true|
    +--------------------+
```

Which would then be aggregated into a single row to read off which columns need to be dropped.

`exprs = df.columns.map( c => max(c).alias(c))`

`drop = df.agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)`

```
    +--------------------+
    |    c1|    c2|    c3|
    +--------------------+
    | false|  true|  true|
    +--------------------+
```

Now any column containing true can be dropped.

**My question is:** Is there better way to do this, performance wise? In this case, does spark stop scanning a column once it finds "foo"? Does it  matter how data is stored (would parquet help?).

Thanks, I'm new here so please tell my how the question can be improved.

Comment: Apart from not actually working, I am not sure how you can short circuit this. Interested to see what the other say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your data, for example, if you have a lot of `foo` values, the code below may perform more efficiently:

```
val colsToDrop = df.columns.filter{ c =>
  !df.where(col(c).like("foo")).limit(1).isEmpty
}

df.drop(colsToDrop: _*)
```

**UPDATE**: Removed redundant `.limit(1)`:

```
val colsToDrop = df.columns.filter{ c =>
  !df.where(col(c).like("foo")).isEmpty
}

df.drop(colsToDrop: _*)
```

Comment: Limit the result set or the search?

Comment: I think `.limit(1)` is unnecessary.

Comment: @LeoC  Why is that? How does the limit work in your opinion?

Comment: `myDF.limit(1)` is a 1-row DataFrame if `myDF` is non-empty, 0-row otherwise.  Hence `myDF.limit(1).isEmpty` is valid for verifying whether `myDF` is empty or not.  Just seems redundant to me.

Comment: That is a good point @LeoC. Here is an implementation of isEmpty:
`def isEmpty: Boolean = withAction("isEmpty", limit(1).groupBy().count().queryExecution) { plan =>
    plan.executeCollect().head.getLong(0) == 0
  }`

Comment: @thebluephantom, the `.limit(n)` is supposed to force stop the computation when resulting dataset already has at least `n` records. In the world of distributed computation  there's a lot more to that, so the `.limit(1)'  does not mean it will be faster, but it is supposed to be

Comment: I take Leo's point. But if I write a complicated SQL query then limit surely only applies to result set after result set computed. Things of nested SQL and correlated sub-queries and inline views. I misread, we agree then.

Comment: Agree, it definitely depends on what's behind the DataFrame. As for `.limit(1).isEmpty` from my answer, the `.limit(1)` is redundant here, since `.isEmpty` calls it inside, so calling it two times does not make any sense

Answer (score 1):

An answer following your logic (worked out correctly), but I think the other answer is better, more so for posterity and your improved ability with Scala. I am not sure the other answer is in fact performant, but neither is this. Not sure if parquet would help, difficult to gauge.

> The other option is to write a loop on the driver and access every
> column and then parquet would be of use due to columnar, stats and
> push down.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def myUDF = udf((cols: Seq[String], cmp: String) => cols.map(code => if (code == cmp) true else false ))

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("foo", "abc", "sss"),
   ("bar", "fff", "sss"),
   ("foo", "foo", "ddd"),
   ("bar", "ddd", "ddd")
   )).toDF("a", "b", "c")

val res = df.select($"*", array(df.columns.map(col): _*).as("colN"))
            .withColumn( "colres", myUDF( col("colN") , lit("foo") )  )

res.show()
res.printSchema()
val n = 3
val res2 = res.select( (0 until n).map(i => col("colres")(i).alias(s"c${i+1}")): _*)
res2.show(false)

val exprs = res2.columns.map( c => max(c).alias(c))
val drop = res2.agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
drop.show(false)
```